# how to convert a #defined item to a string in c++?

Tags: c++, string, constants, c-preprocessor

Suppose I have defined an item

```
#define CLASSNAME MyClass
```

and I then want the preprocessor to generate a string constant     "MyClass"
e.g

```
std::string str("MyClass")
```

I cannot of course write

```
std::string str("CLASSNAME")
```

Because being it between "" CLASSNAME would not be considered as a defined item but as the plain string content.
I don't want to include the "" in the #define i.e

```
#define CLASSNAME "MyClass"
```

because later I may want to call a class MyClass automatically i.e

```
class CLASSNAME
{
}
```

How can I do to have the preprocessor include the "" in the string definition?
Thanks

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/YdrdadqT7

Comment: Thanks Marek R, I really did not know that preprocessor syntax! This definitely does the job